# JsonNode findValue Without Searching Child Nodes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a resource that is structured like so:

```
"activity": {
            "activity_type": "Like",
            "activity_id": "123456",
            "object_id": "",
            "product_id":"",
            "reference_activity": {
                    "activity_type": "Rating",
                    "activity_id": "789456",
                    "object_id": "rating/5",
                    "product_id": "product.v1.13445123",
                    "timestamp": 1433447044000
            },
            "timestamp": 1435790640115
}
```

The problem is that the resource can contain an object of the same class (i.e. referencing another "activity").  As a result, they have similar value names.  I'm trying to parse this JSON structure using Jackson's JsonNode.findValue() method, but the findValue() method does a nested search as well.  So if I do a findValue("object_id"), it will never return the empty string. Instead, it will always return "rating/5".

1. Is there a way to limit the findValue() method to the immediate
   children?
2. Or, is there a way to remove the reference_activity object from the
   parent structure (but still retain the JsonNode object) so that I can parse them separately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need recursive find, just use `path` or `get` methods?

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: That indeed does the trick nicely!