# Using Jackson's JsonNode.findPath(String fieldName) to get the value of a field with a Non-Unique column name

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider the following (simplied) JSON tree structure:

```
  {
      "id": "1",
      "metaData": {
        "name": "nestedName"
      },
      "name": "rootName"
  }
```

I put this stucture in a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode object. To get the String values of these columns, I need only include this statement in my Java code:

```
String id = jsonNode.findPath("id").textValue();
```

I love this not only for its simplicity, but that my code doesn't have to be aware of the JSON tree structure it's parsing. I realize that if I want [root][name] specifically though, I'll have to have some kind of determination logic.

My question is, what is the least amount of logic I will require in order to somehow distinguish/specify what "name" to get? I've looked into the JsonNode.findValues(String fieldName) to get a list of the values, but still not sure how I would then determine which value was coming from which "name" and how to choose the "root" one, or at least, the one closest to the root.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I couldn't find an exact match, so asking again.

Comment: I think it could be solved by using path or get method.
ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733052/jsonnode-findvalue-without-searching-child-nodes

Answer (score 6):

If you want a node directly underneath the root use .get()

```
jsonNode.get("id").textValue();
```

If you want to get "name" but you have problems with ambiguity you can do something like

```
jsonNode.findPath("metaData").findPath("name").textValue();
```

But then of course you know have to know something about the schema.

Comment: You can directly do `findPath("name").asText()` it will find in entire json tree